# version `GLIBC_2.33' not found, 2.32-4 is candidate

Tags: python, glibc, kali-linux, instapy

I am trying to run InstaPy bot on my Raspberry Pi with 32bit Kali Linux installed. Everything is up to date, upgraded and libc6 updated as well. My GLIBC version is 2.32-4 and according to kali repo this is the most actual version.

```
$ ldd --version                                                        1 ⨯
ldd (Debian GLIBC 2.32-4) 2.32

$ apt-cache policy libc6
libc6:
  Installed: 2.32-4
  Candidate: 2.32-4
  Version table:
 *** 2.32-4 500
        500 http://http.kali.org/kali kali-rolling/main armhf Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
```

However if I run bot i get this:

```
$ python3 quickstart.py

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/kali/Downloads/instapy-quickstart-master/quickstart.py", line 2, in <module>
    from instapy import InstaPy
  File "/home/kali/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/instapy/__init__.py", line 6, in <module>
    from .instapy import InstaPy
  File "/home/kali/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/instapy/instapy.py", line 33, in <module>
    from .clarifai_util import check_image
  File "/home/kali/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/instapy/clarifai_util.py", line 3, in <module>
    from clarifai.rest import ClarifaiApp
  File "/home/kali/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/clarifai/rest/__init__.py", line 3, in <module>
    from clarifai.rest.client import ApiClient
  File "/home/kali/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/clarifai/rest/client.py", line 36, in <module>
    from clarifai.rest.grpc.proto.clarifai.api.endpoint_pb2_grpc import V2Stub
  File "/home/kali/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/clarifai/rest/grpc/proto/clarifai/api/endpoint_pb2_grpc.py", line 2, in <module>
    import grpc
  File "/home/kali/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/grpc/__init__.py", line 22, in <module>
    from grpc import _compression
  File "/home/kali/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/grpc/_compression.py", line 15, in <module>
    from grpc._cython import cygrpc
ImportError: /lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.33' not found (required by /home/kali/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/grpc/_cython/cygrpc.cpython-310-arm-linux-gnueabihf.so)
```

I would like to keep Kali I am pretty much used to it. I'd like to point out that I'm not a coder or something just a guy who got his first linux based OS a week ago.

Answer (score 0):

The problem seemed to be incompatible OS. I installed Raspbian and everything went ok.

Comment: Can you explain more, such as what Raspbian OS you installed? I have the same problem with the raspberry PI 4 on Raspberry PI OS 32-bits